# Error compiling C# 6 with Microsoft.Build ( Visual Studio SDK )

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, c#-6.0, visual-studio-sdk, microsoft.build

This is a working C#6 test code. It compiles on VS2015

```
namespace testcode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = null ;
            string y = x?.Substring(0, 2);
            return;
        }       
    }
}
```

The `cproj` has toolsversion `14.0`

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

This is how I'm trying to compile it with **MSBUILD** via the **Visual Studio SDK**

```
//References Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Framework
namespace MSBuildTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pc = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection(Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetDefinitionLocations.Registry);
            pc.DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0";
            pc.RegisterLogger(new Microsoft.Build.Logging.ConsoleLogger(Microsoft.Build.Framework.LoggerVerbosity.Detailed));
            var pr = pc.LoadProject(@"C:\path\to\testcode.cproj");
            pr.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message

> ```
> Program.cs(8,26): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
> Program.cs(8,27): error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
>     0 Warning(s)
>     2 Error(s)
> ```

I guess it's using the wrong MSBUILD executable, but I found no way to force the MSBUILD bin path.

Comment: You are building with C# v5 I guess.

Comment: @DavidG but how do I fix that?

Comment: Perhaps reference the right `Microsoft.Build.*` libraries? What is the full path to them?

Comment: @DavidG But Microsoft.Build.* seems to be part of .Net framework, not of MSBUILD,  I'll check if there are other dll's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing the older version of the `Microsoft.Build.*` libraries, make sure you are pointing at the right ones. If you use old ones you will be trying to build with C# v5 which doesn't understand the null propogation operators.

For example, on my build machine they are:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll

Answer (score 7):

**To Resolve this issue, Try below setting:**

For anyone else that gets this error, don't use the msbuild located at:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Instead use the msbuild at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

Comment: I have found the working msbuild.exe under this path:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe". As you pointed out, the one under the .net framework folder seems to be different and didn't work. Now, weird compiler errors are gone. Thanks!

Comment: @carlos357 Welcome Bro! Feel glad to help you.